# Check if input was not changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, thumbnails

It is possible to check if a input was **not changed** using `change()` event?

I'm working with `<input type='file' />` and i want to warning the user that no changes was made on his own action.

Right now, i just made a normal `change()` event:

```
 // fire the thumbnail (img preview)
$("#file-input").on("change", function () {
    readURL(this); // create the thumbnail
});
```

what i'm missing ?

**Prev Solutuib:**

well, i found a workaround for this, the real problem is that i give a option to the user to hide the thumbnail, and if he wants, open again...

but the thumbnail will only open when the user select a image, that's the problem, because the change event fire this option to open, so, if no change, no thumbnail open.

so, when i hide the thumbnail, i change the `input file`  for a new one, making the change event always fire.

Comment: Value of a `file input` is a fakepath. Does your file input have a default value? How?

Comment: @undefined - but it does get the filename, so it can be compared, just not with the change event, and of course not the path, as that will just be "fakepath" etc.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, it gets the filename, the question is how a file input can have a default value? Surely he want's to check the `file input` on submit event, so if the value of file input is empty he can alert something.

Comment: i think FF generate a url file to make his preview always diferent, so change works perfect. the problem is with chrome, he just dont change anything and do not fire my `change` event

Comment: Chrome fires the change event if there actually is a change, if the same file is selected, it does not fire.

Comment: Yes, that's why i pop-up this question to see if we have any workaround to this problem. Can i run with other event?

Comment: @adeneo i found a workaround, check my edit.

Comment: @RicardoArruda - actually browsed past that solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file), but did'nt think it would fit this problem, good for you!

Comment: @adeneo change your answer with this solution and i accept. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a variable to store the last value of the input, and compare to the current value on change event, if they are the same, no change was made :

```
var last_value = $("#file-input").val();

$("#file-input").on("change", function () {
    if (this.value === last_value) alert('no change');
    last_value=this.value;
});
```

EDIT: Or you can always just replace the input tag with another, like this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file) suggest :

```
var $c  = $("#container");
var $f1 = $("#container .f1");

function FChange() {
    alert("f1 changed");

    $(this).remove();
    $("<input type='file' class='f1' />").change(FChange).appendTo($c);
}

$f1.change(FChange);
```

Comment: but wouldn't the change event not fire if it wasn't changed? I may just be misreading the question... but I like your answer

Comment: Have'nt tested it, but you might be right! Anyway, this was the best I could come up with ?

Comment: And I tested, and you are right, selecting the same file over again does not trigger the change event.

Comment: yeah, definitely, if no changes was mede, the change event do not fire, i can't validate anything inside the change.

Comment: Can't seem to find a workaround, best I could think of would be to bind to the click function on the button, and if no change event was registered within a certain timeframe, it probably did'nt change!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" data-url="intial-value" />

$("#file-input").on("change", function () {
    if($(this).val() != $(this).data('url'){
       //value has changed
       $(this).data('url', $(this).val())
    }
    else{
       return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#file-input").on("change", function () {
    if($(this).data('last-val')){
        // do something
    } else {
       $(this).data('last-val',$(this).val());
       //do something else
    }
 });
```