# ng-change on input type file not called second time if file is same

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I am trying to attach files and try to store them in an array. I have defined a function on a button which removes the file from array.
Now if i attach a file named file1.txt , it gets stored in array and when i click on remove button this file gets removed from array.
If i try to attach the same file again, the function(in ng-change ) which stores the file in arrray is not called but gets called if file is different than before(like file2.txt).
I tried making a directive but gets the same problem. However I made a directive for drag and drop which solves the problem but i need both modes.

Comment: Can you share your code? It's super hard to help you without seeing any code. (please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29983282/edit) your question to include it).

Comment: Sorry But i cant share the code. However i found the solution by setting the value of input field null.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here: [How to detect input type=file "change" for the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file)

But this breaks the cancel button (for Chrome at least), as it will not fire change event to null.