# jQuery on change is not working if choose same file on another row data on loop

Tags: jquery

My jQuery on change is not working if I choose same file on another row data on loop.

```
for($i=$Page_Start;$i<$Page_End;$i++)
{
?>
    <tr class="trClick" id="<?php echo $dData['DESCRIPTIONID'][$i]; ?>" data-toggle="modal">
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

Modal

```
<div id="modalBellDescriptionLoad" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form id="updateDescription" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <input type="file" name="bellToneFileInput" class="bellToneFileInput" id="bellToneFileInput"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".bellToneFileInput").change(function()
{
    alert("Test");
});
```

alert will appear if I choose different file to another row data loop. If same file choose, alert not appear.

Is there something wrong I do on my code?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file

Comment: It might be because the value is not actually changing have you tried calling `$(".bellToneFileInput").val(null);` in your .change() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-select the same file, the value of the input does not change. Although, the event is triggered in `Firefox 57` and is not triggered in `Chrome 61`. I would suggest emptying the value on click.

**Update**: The event is triggered without emptying the value is `Firefox 56` as well, however you must empty the value in `Edge 40` and `IE 11`.

```js
/* Without Clearing Value */
$('#non-empty-upload').change(function() {
  alert(this.files[0].name);
});

/* With Clearing Value */
$('#empty-upload').on('click', function() {
  $(this).val('');
}).on('change', function() {
  alert(this.files[0].name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Without Emptying Value</h2>
<input id="non-empty-upload" type="file">
<hr>
<h2>Emptying Value</h2>
<input id="empty-upload" type="file">
```