# Issue: OnChange event does not fire for Input if it is same file is selected twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to listen to file select event whenever user selects a file (on repeated clicks of the browse 
button).

However, if the user selects the same file as previously, the `change` event does not fire. Is there some other event I could listen to, or other solution to this problem?

```js
(function() {
  $('.file_upload').on('change', function() {
    console.log('Changed!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="btn btn-primary">File #1 <input name="file1" id="file1" class="file_upload a1" type="file" /></label>
```

Comment: well it did not change so why should it fire?

Comment: Maybe you want to listen to blur instead of change?

Comment: Input file field is only a single file at a time. If you want to allow multiple files, you might want to add multiple to your input tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have done your logic for your file upload or whatever you are doing, you can reset the `value` property.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file)

```js
var $f1 = $("#container .f1");

function FChange() {
    alert("f1 changed");
    
    $(this).prop("value", "");
}

$f1.change(FChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <input type="file" class="f1">
</div>
```

Another thing mentioned was that you can actually remove and re add the file input element on change.

Comment: You can't set the value of a file input.

Comment: @epascarello you can, see the snippet.

Comment: @epascarello: I didn't think so either, but it worked. Perhaps you just can't set the value of file input to an actual file, but looks you can set it to nothing = "". Or perhaps you can't set the value in older browsers.

Comment: @dar25 it appears it does not work in legacy browsers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html