# Socket.io: Same image not sending two times in succession

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, socket.io

i have chat application and it has feature you can send images with but i discovered now that it can not send two images two times in succession, but you can send same images two times like this

-send image 1

-send image 2

-send image 1

i also has feature you could paste images and send with (clipboard) and it could send images in succession so i got confused what causes that?
here us my code:

Client side:

```
document.getElementById('fileselect').addEventListener('change', function () {
   if (this.files.length != 0) {
      var file = this.files[0],
          reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {

       this.value = '';
       socket.emit('img', {
            image: e.target.result

       })
    };
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
}, false);
```

and Server-side

```
socket.on('img', function(data) {
io.in(socket.current_room).emit('img', {image: data.image, id: socket.id});
```

What is wrong? What how can i fix it

Comment: It's because the `fileselect` element doesn't get refreshed if you pick the same file twice, therefore the `"change"` event doesn't get triggered. Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file)

Comment: can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, sure thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `fileselect` element doesn't get refreshed if you pick the same file twice, therefore the "change" event doesn't get triggered. Solution here : [How to detect input type=file "change" for the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file)