# Angular input file: Selecting the same file

Tags: html, file, input

I have the following line in HTML:

```html
<input type="file" #fileInput style="display: none"  accept=".xml" (change)="OnFileSelected($event)"/>
```

Upon selecting a file, the OnFileSelected callback is invoked. 
But then, if I select the same file again, this callback is not called.

Can you please help?

Comment: That looks like code to be consumed by Angular, not straight HTML. You may want to [edit] your question to update the tags accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect input type=file "change" for the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109276/how-to-detect-input-type-file-change-for-the-same-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`onChange` will not detect any change to input type file if the same file has been selected. There are 2 possible ways to make `onChange` working on same file selection which I would recommend

1. Either you need to add an event like `onClick` to clear the value so that the change event will work.

   `<input type="file" #fileInput style="display: none"  accept=".xml"  (change)="OnFileSelected($event)" (click)="this.value=null"/>`
2. Add `multiple` attribute to the input element

`<input type="file" #fileInput style="display: none"  accept=".xml" (change)="OnFileSelected($event)" multiple/>`

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by others in comments, you can achieve it like below

`<input type="file" #fileInput style="display: none"  accept=".xml"  (change)="OnFileSelected($event)" (click)="$event.target.value=null"/>`

Comment: (click)="this.value=null" here this.value is not work for me. but (click)="$event.target.value=null" is worked.

Comment: Thanks @SupunKavinda (click)="$event.target.value=null" this one worked for me also

Answer (score 1):

You can also connect to your input element with a element reference and just set it to null when finished.

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;
```

```
this.fileInput.nativeElement.value = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Anand's answer I used the following code:

```
<input type="file" #fileInput style="display: none"  accept=".xml" (change)="OnFileSelected($event)" [(ngModel)]="value"/>
```

In the ts code:

```js
  public OnFileSelected (event)
  {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    this.value = undefined;
  }
```

Best regards,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

> <input type="file" #fileInput style="display: none"  accept=".xml"
> (change)="OnFileSelected($event)" **(click)="fileInput.value = ''"**/>

please add **(click)="fileInput.value = ''"**

In 2023 with Angular 16 this works like a charm