# Function calls get stacked and execute all together when cancel is clicked on file input

Tags: javascript, html, function, file, input

I have a column in a table that has multiple rows in order to select a new image, the onclick of that column event calls the same function triggers a single file input, the onchange event opens a modal with [croppie.js](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie) and then it's returned as a file to an ajax call.

The issue I am having is that when you click on the image the function gets call correctly, opens the file input but if you click cancel and then click another image and click cancel and then a third one and select an image and apply it, the other previous calls get executed and the ajax calls as well updating the 3 images with the same selection.

I have a preview image that is hidden to store the result of the cropping and use the onload event to perform the ajax calls, but is seems to be accumulating and executing when one selection is processed.

When I click on the image to the function, it should trigger the onclick function once and the input file (through for="" label) for selection and if nothing is selected that event should stop there and only work on the currently clicked.

Here is the function:

```js
function livePictureEdit(element) {
  let id = parseInt(
    document.getElementById(event.target.id).getAttribute("data-id")
  );
  let uuid = document.getElementById(event.target.id).getAttribute("data-uuid");
  let type = document.getElementById(event.target.id).getAttribute("data-type");
  let action = document
    .getElementById(event.target.id)
    .getAttribute("data-action");
  let value = "";

  //Here seems to be the stacking of events
  $("#student_picture_preview").on("load", function () {
    value = $("#student_picture_preview").attr("src");
    //Ajax call with all the params
    commitLiveEdit(id, uuid, value, type, action);
  });
}
```

Here is the onclick event assigned to every image the column on row generation before applying datatbles (the same label with the same onclick event on every row):

```
<label for="student_picture" id="livePictureEdit_<?php echo $data["id"]?>" onclick="livePictureEdit(this);"  data-type="student" data-uuid="<?php echo $_SESSION["csrfToken"]; ?>" data-action="picture" data-id="<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>">
</label>
```

The input and the img used for preview at the end of the body

```html
<input type="file" id="student_picture" style="display: none" accept="image/jpeg, image/png">
<img id="student_picture_preview" class="liveEdit p-0 m-0" style="display: none;">
```

If anyone has any help that would be greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Canceling means the input still "contains" the same file that was selected before. This could probably help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4109276/1427878

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT ANSWER:** I found the answer, I had to detach the onload event of the preview image to prevent the stacking and reassign again on every click:

```
function livePictureEdit(element){

let id = parseInt(document.getElementById(event.target.id).getAttribute("data-id"));
let uuid = document.getElementById(event.target.id).getAttribute("data-uuid");
let type = document.getElementById(event.target.id).getAttribute("data-type");
let action = document.getElementById(event.target.id).getAttribute("data-action");
let value = "";
$("#student_picture_preview").off('load'); //<----- Detach the load event for every click and attach it again to have the corresponding item click after
    $("#student_picture_preview").on('load', function(){
    value = $("#student_picture_preview").attr('src');
    //Ajax call with all the params
     commitLiveEdit(id,uuid,value,type,action);
    });
```

}